# SwiftUI handler to capture tapped link in markdown Text view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In Swift 5.5 SwiftUI it's now possible to have links in markdown text. Is it possible to use this to add a tap handler for subtext in a `Text` view? For example, I'm imagining doing something like the following, but I haven't figured out how to construct a link that would work for this (I just get URL errors each time). Would setting up some kind of custom url schema work? Is there a better solution that doing that, like something I can add to the `Text` view that acts similar to `UITextView`'s `shouldInteractWith`? The goal is to solve similar problems to what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624838/swiftui-tappable-subtext) but without having to fall back to UITextView or non-wrapping HStacks or GeometryReaders with ZStacks.

```swift
let baseText = "apple banana pear orange lemon"
let clickableText = baseText.split(separator: " ")
                            .map{ "[\($0)](domainThatImAllowedToCapture.../\($0))" }
Text(.init(clickableText)).onOpenLink { link in
  print(link.split(separator: "/").last) // prints "pear" if word pear is tapped.
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you could try something like this example code. It loops over your `baseText`, creates the appropriate links, and when the link is tapped/actioned you can put some more code to deal with it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let baseText = "apple banana pear orange lemon"
    let baseUrl = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q="
    
    var body: some View {
        let clickableText = baseText.split(separator: " ").map{ "[\($0)](\(baseUrl)\($0))" }
        ForEach(clickableText, id: \.self) { txt in
            let attributedString = try! AttributedString(markdown: txt)
            Text(attributedString)
                .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
                    print("---> link actioned: \(txt.split(separator: "=").last)" )
                    return .systemAction
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great. I've modified it a bit in the below answer to show what I'm using for my solution, but this effectively did it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. It should be noted however that this solution is available only on iOS 15 and above. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/openurlaction/init(handler:)

Comment: yes, correct, like on 72% of all devices introduced in the last four years use iOS 15.
ref: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

Answer (score 0):

Using the method described by @workingdog, I've cleaned this up into the following working solution:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ClickableText: View {
  @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
  
  private var text: String
  private var onClick: (_ : String) -> Void
  
  init(text: String, _ onClick: @escaping (_ : String) -> Void) {
    self.text = text
    self.onClick = onClick
  }

  var body: some View {
    Text(.init(toClickable(text)))
      .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
      .accentColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
      .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
        let trimmed = url.path
          .replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "")
          .trimmingCharacters(in: .letters.inverted)
        withAnimation {
          onClick(trimmed)
        }
        return .discarded
      })
  }
  
  private func toClickable(_ text: String) -> String {
    // Needs to be a valid URL, but otherwise doesn't matter.
    let baseUrl = "https://a.com/"
    return text.split(separator: " ").map{ word in
      var cleaned = String(word)
      for keyword in ["(", ")", "[", "]"] {
        cleaned = String(cleaned.replacingOccurrences(of: keyword, with: "\\\(keyword)"))
      }
      return "[\(cleaned)](\(baseUrl)\(cleaned))"
    }.joined(separator: " ")
  }
}
```

Comment: no display correct markdown IOS16