# Is it possible it use a link in a SwiftUI AttributedString to navigate to another view in the same app?

Tags: swift, swiftui, deep-linking, swiftui-navigationstack

I know with AttributedString, I can link to an external website using something like:

`Text("To learn more about AttributedString visit [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring/)")`

Can I use this to go from ViewA to ViewB within the same app, kind of like this example in Twitter?

[image: Twitter]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listen to link click in SwiftUI TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192976/listen-to-link-click-in-swiftui-textview)

Answer (score 7):

You can store an [`OpenURLAction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/openurlaction#) in the environment to override how subviews like `Text` and `Link` open URLs.

This example is from the documentation:

> ```
> Text("Visit [Example Company](https://www.example.com) for details.")
>     .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
>         handleURL(url) // Define this method to take appropriate action.
>         return .handled
>     })
> ```

You may want to apply the `environment` modifier at a high level of your view hierarchy (near your root view) rather than directly on each `Text` view.