# Creating an inline text link that will open up another view in my application

Tags: swiftui, nsattributedstring, custom-url

I'm trying to create a view in my app that displays a chunk of text. I want certain words within that text to be a clickable link that opens up another view. I've been googling for a long time and can't seem to find the right approach.

Simply trying to do things like `HStack{ Text("example text") Button("word"), action) Text("rest of example text") }` don't work as it really screws up the overall layout of the chunk of text.

I'm also looking into attributed string. I'm wondering if I can make a custom url that points to the view in my app that I want and then apply that to the attributed string. Is that possible?

What's the best approach here?

When I try to open the view inside handling the clicked url nothing happens. Is it just not possible to do this? Do I need to navigate to another swiftUi view instead?

```
struct shortStoryView: View {
    @State var showPopUpScreen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            ZStack{
                Image("homeWallpaper")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, alignment: .center)
                    .opacity(1.0)
                
                testStory(showNewScreen: self.$showPopUpScreen).frame(width: 350, height:500).background(Color.white.opacity(0.75)).cornerRadius(20).overlay( RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 6))
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct testStory: View{
        @Binding var showNewScreen: Bool
        
        var body: some View{
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                    Text("Cristoforo Colombo [nasce](myappurl://action) nel 1451 vicino a Genova, nel nord Italia. A 14 anni diventa marinaio e viaggia in numerosi Paesi. Per Cristoforo Colombo la Terra è rotonda e verso la fine del ‘400, vuole viaggiare verso l’India e vuole farlo con un viaggio verso ovest. La spedizione è costosa e Colombo prima chiede aiuto al re del Portogallo e poi alla regina Isabella di Castiglia. Nel 1492, dopo mesi di navigazione, scopre però un nuovo continente: l’America, che viene chiamata il Nuovo Mondo. Cristoforo Colombo fa altri viaggi in America ma ormai non è più così amato e così muore nel 1506 povero e dimenticato da tutti.")
                        .modifier(textModifer())
                        .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
                            handleURL(url)
                        })
                }
            }
        
        func handleURL(_ url: URL) -> OpenURLAction.Result {
            popUpView()
            return .handled
        }
    }
    
    struct popUpView: View{
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
        
        var body: some View{
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Text("Nascire - To be Born")
                    .font(Font.custom("Arial Hebrew", size: 20))
                    .background(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                
                Button(action: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()},
                       label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listen to link click in SwiftUI TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192976/listen-to-link-click-in-swiftui-textview)

Comment: sort of? I added some of my code to try and implement what they were describing. I debugged through the application and my code is indeed hitting the handleUrl method whenever the inline text link is pressed but the call to open the popUpView() doesn't cause the view to appear on the screen

Comment: You can’t have a view in a handler but you can change a Bool. The Bool can show/hide the view

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you are looking for but this is what I did as a work around.

```
NavigationLink {
    RandomView()
} label: {
    Group {
        Text("Your text")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
            
        + Text("More text")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundStyle(Color(.systemBlue))
    }
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
}
```

I made the whole text a navigation link. I am not sure how to make just one Text() the nav link unless you want to put them side by side in a hstack but that might look odd if the users device is small or the text is long and spills over.