# How to dynamically combine multiple Text views with onTapGesture modifiers in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

[Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-combine-text-views-together) I see that you can add multiple Text views together. Is there a way to do the same thing when the Text views each have an onTapGesture modifier and, if possible, an onHover modifier on macOS? The below code works without the onTapGesture modifier.

```
struct ContentView: View {

let sentence = "Combining text views like this is as close as we get to attributed strings in SwiftUI – there is no support for using NSAttributedString at this time. Combining text views like this is as close as we get to attributed strings in SwiftUI – there is no support for using NSAttributedString at this time. Combining text views like this is as close as we get to attributed strings in SwiftUI – there is no support for using NSAttributedString at this time. Combining text views like this is as close as we get to attributed strings in SwiftUI – there is no support for using NSAttributedString at this time. Combining text views like this is as close as we get to attributed strings in SwiftUI – there is no support for using NSAttributedString at this time."

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        textView()
    }
}

private func textView() -> Text {
    var combinedView = Text("")
    for word in sentence.split(separator: " ") {
        let currentText = Text(word)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .onTapGesture { print(word) } as! Text
        combinedView = combinedView + Text(" ") + currentText
    }
    return combinedView
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192976/listen-to-link-click-in-swiftui-textview/75201168#75201168

Comment: That has the same issue for me, once the modifier is applied it no longer is a Text but "some View"

Comment: You can use that solution to trigger unique actions that is the closest you’ll get.

Comment: I found this (https://github.com/tevelee/SwiftUI-Flow) which I think will do the trick