# Int/String is being converted into something else when using in Hyper link in Text() - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to use hyper link in the Text(). But whenever the link is made `Int` type **id** is being converted into some thing like this `arif-test.swiftuirnd.app/content/%25lld`. And I am getting an error when triggering the link.

> Failed to open URL arif-test.swiftuirnd.app/content/%25lld: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "invalid input parameters" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=invalid input parameters, _LSLine=282, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:fileHandle:options:completionHandler:]}

`arif-test.swiftuirnd.app` is one of the ***Associated Domains*** of the app.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomText: View {
    private let id: Int
    
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Click this")
            +
            Text(" ")
            +
            Text("[link](arif-test.swiftuirnd.app/content/\(id))")
        }
        .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
            print(url)
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    CustomText(id: 123)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour. What seems to be happening here is that SwiftUI is parsing the markdown *before* substituting in the `id`.

Note that `\(id)` here is not your normal string interpolation. The string literal is a `LocalizedStringKey`, and you are calling [this overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:tablename:bundle:comment:)) of `Text.init`.

You can use the other overload that takes an `AttributedString` instead. Write a helper method like this:

```
func link(_ label: String, _ url: String) -> AttributedString {
    // optionally, localise the label and/or url here...

    var attrStr = AttributedString(label)
    attrStr.link = URL(string: url)
    return attrStr
}
```

Usage:

```
Text(link("Link", "https://example.com/\(id)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use this view modifier to receive URLs in a particular scene within your app

```
.onOpenURL(perform: { url in
    print(url)
})
```

It usually belongs at the very top of the app. It isn't designed to work locally.

But...

`OpenURLAction` is intended to be used in the manner that your sample depicts.

> Any views that read the action from the environment, including the built-in Link view and Text views with markdown links, or links in attributed strings, use your action. Initialize an action by calling the init(handler:) initializer with a handler that takes a URL and returns an OpenURLAction.Result:

```
.environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
    handleURL(url) // Define this method to take appropriate action.
    return .handled
})
```

With either solution though you need a valid URL.

You can use something like "[link](myApp://arif-test.swiftuirnd.app/content/(id))"

You can find some additional info

[Listen to link click in SwiftUI TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192976/listen-to-link-click-in-swiftui-textview/75201168#75201168)

And in the documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/openurlaction