# Is this the proper way to make a SwiftUI Text hyperlink clickable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

In general, my app is using the camera to recognize barcodes and appending the barcode to the rest of the URL.

---

```
LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
    ForEach(vm.recognizedItems) { item in
        switch item {
            case .barcode(let barcode):
                switch (vm.displayHyperlink) {
                    case true:
                        Text("https://my.url.com/sub/\(barcode.payloadStringValue ?? "Unknown barcode")")
```

---

Really, the relevant piece is the last line. When the camera recognizes a barcode, it generates a Text object with the URL. The URL displays correctly (e.g., https://my.url.com/sub/ABC123). Swift even turns the text blue and makes it tappable, recognizing that it is like a URL; however, when I tap on the URL, it brings me to a 404. The subdomain and the appended barcode value are cut off of the URL in Safari.

Is there a different way I should be doing this? I figured that Swift automatically recognizing it as a URL and turning it into a hyperlink meant it had handled the formatting. And yes, I have verified that this URL works when entered manually.

Sorry if this is a simple question, I'm new to Swift but trying to learn. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77897954/5133585

Comment: Use `AttributedString`?

Comment: AttributedString worked! For anyone who wants my specific usage, I used the function from the answer of Sweeper's link and modified the line in question like so:

    Text(link("Open in Safari", "https://my.url.com/sub/\(barcode.payloadStringValue ?? "Unknown barcode")"))