# Swift UI Layout Protocol Not functioning properly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using the Layout protocol to layout an array of views in a custom fashion. I want the layout protocol to layout the subviews in a way like a single text block. Meaning the sub views should start from the left then grow horizontally to the right, once all horizontal space is filled then a new line is created below. My current layout protocol has some bugs where wide array elements stretch out of the view and do not split into new lines. Also the flow layout sometimes doesn't use all the available horizontal space.

I tried defining a max width but this did not work.

[image: p1]

```
import SwiftUI

struct MessageAudioRecorder: View {
    var body: some View {
        FlowLayout {
            Text("Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello")
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Text("111111111111111111").foregroundStyle(.blue)
            }
            Text("Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello")
            Text("111111111111111111").foregroundStyle(.orange)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    MessageAudioRecorder()
}

struct FlowLayout: Layout {
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        let sizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }
        
        var lineX = bounds.minX
        var lineY = bounds.minY
        var lineHeight: CGFloat = 0
        
        for index in subviews.indices {
            if lineX + sizes[index].width > (proposal.width ?? 0) {
                lineY += lineHeight
                lineHeight = 0
                lineX = bounds.minX
            }
            
            subviews[index].place(
                at: .init(
                    x: lineX + sizes[index].width / 2,
                    y: lineY + sizes[index].height / 2
                ),
                anchor: .center,
                proposal: ProposedViewSize(sizes[index])
            )
            
            lineHeight = max(lineHeight, sizes[index].height)
            lineX += sizes[index].width
        }
    }
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
           let sizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }
           
           var totalHeight: CGFloat = 0
           var totalWidth: CGFloat = 0
           
           var lineWidth: CGFloat = 0
           var lineHeight: CGFloat = 0
           
             for size in sizes {
               if lineWidth + size.width > proposal.width ?? 0 {
                   totalHeight += lineHeight
                   lineWidth = size.width
                   lineHeight = size.height
               } else {
                   lineWidth += size.width
                   lineHeight = max(lineHeight, size.height)
               }

               totalWidth = max(totalWidth, lineWidth)
           }

           totalHeight += lineHeight
           
           return .init(width: totalWidth, height: totalHeight)
       }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like a two-day old topic coming back to life again.  Anyway, how is the screenshot you post there related to the code implementation?  I don't see a phrase that says "The The Big Lie was the most important thing in" or "Everyone go share ur success" in the code.

Comment: @ElTomato I revised the question from the previous and made it much simpler and easier to reproduce. I updated the photo.

Comment: It fails because the first two `Text` views are longer than the device width.

Comment: @ElTomato thats what my question already says is the problem.

Comment: I don't think the Layout protocol is the right guy for you in this case.  That's just my opinion.

Comment: @ElTomato then how do you propose I get the desired effect?

Comment: A custom `Layout` is only able to position the subviews it is given, it cannot break them up unto smaller pieces. If all you want to do is build up a paragraph of text then you could break up the source text into individual words and combine them again with `Text` concatenation, or use them as building blocks in your flow layout.

Comment: @BenzyNeez okay that makes sense, but I want to have buttons also and other views not just texts. I dont only want to concatenate text blocks

Comment: If you have a `Button` view included, I cannot think of anything.

Comment: Why not AttributedString and/or markup?

Comment: @loremipsum how do I do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192976/listen-to-link-click-in-swiftui-textview/75201168#75201168

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-advanced-text-styling-using-attributedstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following structure correctly allows you to combine any amount of unique views in a "flow" layout where views are placed starting from left to right, once the horizontal space runs out then the next views go below. This structure also correctly splits up views that are too wide. My implementation also allows custom alignment and spacing between views. This was made to combine buttons and text blocks into a paragraph like fashion but it will work with anything.

```
struct CustomLayout: Layout {
    var alignment: Alignment = .leading
    var spacing: CGFloat = 0
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let maxWidth = proposal.width ?? 0
        var height: CGFloat = 0
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)
        
        for (index, row) in rows.enumerated() {
            if index == (rows.count - 1) {
                height += row.maxHeight(proposal)
            } else {
                height += row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing
            }
        }
        
        return .init(width: maxWidth, height: height)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        var origin = bounds.origin
        let maxWidth = bounds.width
        
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)
        
        for row in rows {
            let leading: CGFloat = bounds.maxX - maxWidth
            let trailing = bounds.maxX - (row.reduce(CGFloat.zero) { partialResult, view in
                let width = view.sizeThatFits(proposal).width
                
                if view == row.last {
                    return partialResult + width
                }
                return partialResult + width + spacing
            })
            let center = (trailing + leading) / 2
            
            origin.x = (alignment == .leading ? leading : alignment == .trailing ? trailing : center)
            
            for view in row {
                let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
                view.place(at: origin, proposal: proposal)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            }
        
            origin.y += (row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing)
        }
    }
    
    func generateRows(_ maxWidth: CGFloat, _ proposal: ProposedViewSize, _ subviews: Subviews) -> [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] {
        var row: [LayoutSubviews.Element] = []
        var rows: [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] = []
        
        var origin = CGRect.zero.origin
        
        for view in subviews {
            let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
            
            if (origin.x + viewSize.width + spacing) > maxWidth {
                rows.append(row)
                row.removeAll()
                origin.x = 0
                row.append(view)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            } else {
                row.append(view)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            }
        }

        if !row.isEmpty {
            rows.append(row)
            row.removeAll()
        }
        
        return rows
    }
}

extension [LayoutSubviews.Element] {
    func maxHeight(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize) -> CGFloat {
        return self.compactMap { view in
            return view.sizeThatFits(proposal).height
        }.max() ?? 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `check lineX + sizes[index].width > (proposal.width ?? 0)` seems weird: it places the subview's center at `lineX + sizes[index].width / 2`, which causes the view to go out of bounds if it is too wide. When it should wrap to a new line, it does not reset the `lineHeight`, which can cause overlap or unnecessary spacing.

Instead, you could try (not tested) to place the subview starting from `lineX`, not its center: that should prevent it from stretching out of the bounds. Set the anchor to `.leading` to make sure the view starts at `lineX` and does not overflow. When wrapping, do reset `lineHeight` to accommodate the next line without overlap or unnecessary space.

```swift
struct FlowLayout: Layout {
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        let sizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }
        
        var lineX = bounds.minX
        var lineY = bounds.minY
        var lineHeight: CGFloat = 0
        
        for index in subviews.indices {
            // Check if the current subview needs to wrap to the next line.
            // The center is no longer used to determine the placement.
            if lineX + sizes[index].width > bounds.maxX {
                lineY += lineHeight
                lineHeight = 0
                lineX = bounds.minX
            }
            
            // Place the subview at the start of the available space.
            subviews[index].place(
                at: CGPoint(x: lineX, y: lineY + sizes[index].height / 2),
                anchor: .leading, // Change the anchor to leading
                proposal: ProposedViewSize(sizes[index])
            )
            
            lineHeight = max(lineHeight, sizes[index].height)
            lineX += sizes[index].width
        }
    }
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        // That function remains largely the same, but make sure it respects the proposal's width.
        // (rest of the function)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks VonC I think this should work too.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Sorry, by the time I got to it, it was already closed.

Comment: VonC, thanks a lot anyways. Maybe look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78091668/swift-ui-store-video-asset-for-later-use