# How to store video asset for later use?

Tags: swiftui

I have a bunch of video players in a scroll view and when a video appears the video is fetched from the URL and played with the AVPlayer. If I scroll away then scroll back the video reloads because the view is destroyed. Is there a way I can get the video data and store it in variable so that the video doesn't have to reload every time? If I could store the video data in a variable I can also pass it between views. How would I implement this with my example?

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
    let example = "example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fom7lDNjP7thxTuowYtsUXbErvX2jhzH/view?usp=sharing"
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            //some views
            
            VideoPlayerView(url: URL(string: example)!)
            
            //some views
        }
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    let url: URL
    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
    @State var aspect: CGSize = CGSize(width: 16, height: 9)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: $player, showControls: false)
                .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fit)
                .onTapGesture {
                   //enter full screen from here while still playing from same duration
                }
        }
        .onAppear {
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)
 
            Task {
                do {
                    if let final = try await getVideoResolution(url: url.absoluteString) {
                        self.aspect = final
                    }
                } catch { }
            }
            
            self.player.play()
        }
    }
}

func getVideoResolution(url: String) async throws -> CGSize? {
    guard let track = try await AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: url)!).loadTracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { return nil }
    let size = try await track.load(.naturalSize).applying(track.load(.preferredTransform))
    return size
}

struct VideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var player : AVPlayer
    let showControls: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {

        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = showControls
        controller.allowsVideoFrameAnalysis = false
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) { }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just the matter of having a URL in memory as a variable?

Comment: A long shot here, but you could try giving
the `VideoPlayerView(url: URL(string: example)!).id(123)` a specific `id`.
In theory the View refresh will try not to re-compute it.

Comment: @ElTomato no that doesn't work

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine okay thanks. Isn't there a AVasset?

Comment: A sophisticated approach would be to store the video URL and the current time in a model, then pause the video when the view gets off screen and resume it when the view reappears.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/offline_playback_and_storage/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and cache the [`AVPlayerItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem) or [`AVAsset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset) associated with each video URL.
That way, you can reuse the player item whenever the video needs to be displayed again, significantly improving the user experience by eliminating unnecessary reloads.

The cache can be implemented using a simple dictionary where the keys are the video URLs (as `String`) and the values are [`AVPlayerItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem) instances. That cache is stored in a shared manager ([singleton pattern](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/managing-a-shared-resource-using-a-singleton)) to allow easy access from anywhere in your app.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

// Singleton manager for caching video assets
class VideoCacheManager {
    static let shared = VideoCacheManager()
    private init() {}
    
    var cache: [String: AVPlayerItem] = [:]
    
    func playerItem(for url: URL) -> AVPlayerItem {
        if let item = cache[url.absoluteString] {
            return item
        } else {
            let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
            cache[url.absoluteString] = item
            return item
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    let example = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fom7lDNjP7thxTuowYtsUXbErvX2jhzH/view?usp=sharing"
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            //some views
            
            VideoPlayerView(url: URL(string: example)!)
            
            //some views
        }
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    let url: URL
    @State private var player: AVPlayer?
    @State var aspect: CGSize = CGSize(width: 16, height: 9)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if let player = player {
                VideoPlayer(player: player, showControls: false)
                    .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fit)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        //enter full screen from here while still playing from same duration
                    }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            let playerItem = VideoCacheManager.shared.playerItem(for: url)
            self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
 
            Task {
                do {
                    if let final = try await getVideoResolution(url: url.absoluteString) {
                        self.aspect = final
                    }
                } catch { }
            }
            
            self.player?.play()
        }
    }
}

// Your existing getVideoResolution function and VideoPlayer struct remain unchanged.
```

But: depending on the size and number of videos you intend to cache, you might need to implement a more sophisticated cache management strategy to avoid excessive memory usage.

---

As noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78091668/swift-ui-store-video-asset-for-later-use/78092291#comment137672627_78091668) by [lorem ipsum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12738750/lorem-ipsum), using [AVFoundation for offline playback and storage of HTTP Live Streams (HLS)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/managing-a-shared-resource-using-a-singleton) could be an alternative approach to handling video content in your SwiftUI application.

The documentation outlines how to download HLS content and store it on the device for offline playback. That involves using [`AVAssetDownloadURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetdownloadurlsession) along with [`AVAssetDownloadTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetdownloadtask) to manage the download of HLS streams. Once downloaded, the content can be played back offline using `AVPlayer`.

You would need to:

- check for cached content before attempting to download content
- download HLS content if said content is not already cached, using `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`.
- play back the video content from the local cache using `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerItem` initialized with the locally stored assets.

```swift
import AVFoundation

class VideoCacheManager {
    static let shared = VideoCacheManager()
    private var backgroundSessionConfiguration: URLSessionConfiguration
    private var assetDownloadURLSession: AVAssetDownloadURLSession
    
    private init() {
        backgroundSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.yourapp.videocache")
        assetDownloadURLSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: backgroundSessionConfiguration, assetDownloadDelegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    }
    
    func downloadAssetIfNeeded(for url: URL) {
        // Check if the asset is already downloaded or in the process of downloading.
        // If not, create an AVAssetDownloadTask for the given URL.
    }
    
    // Implement AVAssetDownloadDelegate methods to handle download progress, completion, and errors.
}

extension VideoCacheManager: AVAssetDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        // Handle successful download. Store reference to the downloaded asset for playback.
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        // Handle errors.
    }
}
```

Note that this method is specifically tailored to HLS content. If your application uses a different video format, you may need to a different strategy.

---

> Caching the video temporary seems like the best idea.
> When I scroll away from the video and scroll back, the app crashes because an `Avasset` can only be used by one instance of an `AVPlayer`.
> I tried to set the player to nil when the view disappears, but this didn't solve the crash.

`AVAsset` and its subclasses, like `AVURLAsset`, are not inherently thread-safe for certain operations, and managing their lifecycle alongside `AVPlayer` instances can be tricky.

You would need to make sure each `AVPlayer` instance has its own `AVPlayerItem`, and by extension, its own `AVAsset`, even if the underlying media content is the same.

- Adjust the caching mechanism to store the video data temporarily on disk rather than caching `AVPlayerItem` or `AVAsset` instances directly. That way, each time you need an `AVPlayerItem`, you create a new instance using the locally stored video data.
- Manage properly the lifecycle of each `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerItem` instance to avoid retaining them longer than necessary, especially when the corresponding view disappears.

The `VideoCacheManager`, focusing on caching video data temporarily, would be:

```swift
class VideoCacheManager {
    static let shared = VideoCacheManager()
    private init() {}
    
    // A dictionary to keep track of ongoing downloads.
    var downloadsInProgress: [URL: URLSessionDownloadTask] = [:]
    
    // Function to download and cache the video temporarily if not already cached.
    func downloadVideoIfNeeded(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        // Check if the video is already being downloaded.
        if let _ = downloadsInProgress[url] {
            // Handle the case where a download is already in progress.
            return
        }
        
        // Start a new download.
        let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (tempFileUrl, response, error) in
            // Remove the download task from the tracking dictionary.
            self.downloadsInProgress.removeValue(forKey: url)
            
            guard let tempFileUrl = tempFileUrl, error == nil else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            // Optionally, move the downloaded file to a temporary location of your choosing.
            // For simplicity, this example uses the original tempFileUrl.
            
            completion(tempFileUrl)
        }
        
        // Keep track of the download task.
        downloadsInProgress[url] = downloadTask
        
        // Start the download.
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}
```

You would then modify `VideoPlayerView` to use `VideoCacheManager` to download and cache the video data, initializing the `AVPlayer` with a new `AVPlayerItem` created from the cached data when needed:

```swift
.onAppear {
    VideoCacheManager.shared.downloadVideoIfNeeded(from: url) { [weak self] localUrl in
        guard let self = self, let localUrl = localUrl else { return }
        
        // Create a new AVPlayerItem for the local URL.
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: localUrl)
        
        // Initialize the AVPlayer with the new AVPlayerItem.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            self.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
.onDisappear {
    // Properly deallocate the AVPlayer and its item to avoid any crashes.
    self.player?.pause()
    self.player = nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks, caching the video temporary seems like the best idea. When I scroll away from the video and scroll back the app crashes because an Avasset can only be used by one instance of an AVPlayer. I tried to set the player to nil when the view disappears but this didn't solve the crash.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower OK, I have updated the answer to propose a better lifecycle management of each AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem instances.

Comment: Thanks ended up working good. Can you look at either of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78094943/swift-device-orientation-updating-incorrectly?noredirect=1#comment137677408_78094943  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78094672/matched-geometry-effect-doesnt-animate-correctly?noredirect=1#comment137676879_78094672