# Matched geometry effect doesn't work with window

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a square that is embedded within a scroll view inside a subview. When the square is clicked I want to animate it to the top of the view hierarchy and present it above everything else, including .sheets, using a matched geometry effect. I cannot get the animation to work. When the square presented at the top is dismissed it should animate back down to the original view.

**Problem**
I present the square at the top of the view hierarchy through a window which makes the animation fail. How can I correctly animate with a window? How can I add basic match geometry effects, transitions, and other animations with windows?

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var popRoot: PopToRoot
    @Namespace private var animation
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "squareAnim", in: animation)
                .foregroundStyle(.blue).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        popRoot.showOverlay = true
                    }
                }
            //other sub views
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View { //top of view hierarchy
     @EnvironmentObject var popRoot: PopToRoot
     @Namespace private var animation
     var body: some View {
          SomeView()
             .overlay {
                    if showOverlay {
                        TopViewWindow()
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "squareAnim", in: animation)
                            // ----- HERE
                    }
             }
     }
}

class PopToRoot: ObservableObject { //envirnment object to be accessed anywhere
    @Published var showOverlay = false
}
```

**video player that goes above everything**

```
struct TopView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .foregroundStyle(.blue).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            
            //other views
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct TopViewWindow: View {
    @State private var hostingController: UIHostingController<TopView>? = nil

    func showImage() {
        let swiftUIView = TopView()
        hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
        hostingController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        hostingController?.view.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
            height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

        if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
           let window = windowScene.windows.first {
            // withAnimation { doesnt work here either
            window.addSubview(hostingController!.view)

            hostingController?.view.center.x = window.center.x
        }
    }
    func dismissImage() {
        hostingController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        hostingController = nil
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {}.onAppear { showImage() }.onDisappear { dismissImage() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Binding Is for value types, it doesn’t do anything for AVPlayer you can use let

Comment: @loremipsum noted, thanks. That won't fix the issue though I am assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

## Here's everything you need to get this working:

### SwiftUI isn't going to be able to match `matchedGeometryEffect`s if they're wrapped inside of a `UIHostingController`

Sorry, but you're trying to inject a SwiftUI view (wrapped in a UIHostingController) into your `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first`. There's just no way SwiftUI will be able to match up your `matchedGeometryEffect`s. If for some reason you really need to have a `UIHostingController` layer, I would recommend doing the `matchedGeometryEffect` with a placeholder and then once the animation is finished, quickly swapping the placeholder out with a `UIHostingController`. If you do this instantly with no animations, the user won't know the difference.

### Put the `.frame(width: 50, height: 50)` lines after the `matchedGeometryEffect`

This will create a smooth animation between the sizes. This is because you're telling SwiftUI the core element that needs to stay the same. When you put the `frame` after, you're saying "Transition this blue rectangle through these size changes"

### Pass your namespace around using this syntax `let namespace: Namespace.ID`

This makes sure the view doesn't get lost from SwiftUI's perspective

### Use a top level `if` statement (optional)

`matchedGeometryEffect` relies on one view being removed while another is inserted at the exact same time. I like to have the if statement at the top level so it's clear where the transition happens. It makes it easier to see instead of burying the if statement inside low level views.

## Full working copy/pasteable example

```swift
class PopToRoot: ObservableObject {
  static let shared = PopToRoot()
  private init() {}
  
  @Published var showOverlay = false
}

struct TopView: View {

  @ObservedObject var popToRoot = PopToRoot.shared
  let namespace: Namespace.ID // Pass namespace like this
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "squareAnim", in: namespace)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100) // Move frame here
        .onTapGesture {
          withAnimation {
            popToRoot.showOverlay = false
          }
        }
      
      //other views
    }
      .ignoresSafeArea()
  }
}

struct SomeView: View {

  @ObservedObject var popToRoot = PopToRoot.shared
  let namespace: Namespace.ID // Pass namespace like this
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "squareAnim", in: namespace)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50) // Move frame here
        .onTapGesture {
          withAnimation {
            popToRoot.showOverlay = true
          }
        }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var popToRoot = PopToRoot.shared
  @Namespace private var namespace
  
  var body: some View {
    
    if popToRoot.showOverlay { // Top level if statement (optional)
      TopView(namespace: namespace)
    } else {
      SomeView(namespace: namespace)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. However I already knew how to do this with swift ui. I understand this is not possible with a hosting controller. The only reason I want to use a hosting controller is because I want to present a view above .sheets and fullscreencovers. The only way I found was a hosting controller. Your solution doesn’t solve animating a hosting controller. Maybe you know of alternative way to animate the view in this manner while presenting the view above everything.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Then you need to do what the top part of my answer says: `If for some reason you really need to have a UIHostingController layer, I would recommend doing the matchedGeometryEffect with a placeholder and then once the animation is finished, quickly swapping the placeholder out with a UIHostingController.`

Comment: Okay thanks. That wouldnt work though. The placeholder is not a hosting controller so it would not go above .sheets and .fullscreencovers. So using a temporary placeholder then quickly swapping it wouldn’t work because the placeholder view wouldn’t even animate above everything.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Is this the core reason why you're using a hosting controller? Because you want the UI on top of everything else?

What's the real problem you're trying to solve here? At this point, you have so many layers of issues stacked on top of each other (hosting controller can't matchedGeoEffect with SwiftUI, SwiftUI can't z-index on top of sheets, etc.)

I can keep suggesting bandaids to patch these limitations but maybe there's a better way to accomplish the core effect you're going for.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Yes the only reason I use a hosting controller is because I want the UI above everything. But since you said hosting controller can't animate with Swift UI then maybe hosting controller isn't the answer. I simply want a UI that can animate to the very top and lay above everything. Maybe you can propose a better approach, thanks.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Yeah this is an annoying limitation with SwiftUI right now. Basically you want to put all your `.sheet` at the top level of your app (maybe just a layer or two below your top level `WindowGroup`). When you start your `MatchedGeoEffect`, you'll want to set a global `hideSheets = true` flag that closes any open sheets. You can write a custom `isPresented` binding that reads from `hideSheets` and your other state. Unfortunately these kind of hacky workarounds are a part of SwiftUI right now until they release some equivalent for UIKit's `UIModalTransitionStyle`.

Comment: Thanks Ill try that out, although if I dismiss a sheet I dont see how I can reopen it after I dismiss the topview, especially after multiple nested sheets and screen covers get closed.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the animation namespace is shared correctly across the different views that participate in the animation. From your code, it appears that separate namespaces are being used in `ContentView` and `BottomVideoView`, which might be causing the issue with the animation not working as expected.

The namespace used for the matched geometry effect should be declared in a common ancestor view and passed down to all child views that need it. That way, the same animation namespace is used across your views.
The ID used with `.matchedGeometryEffect` (as described in "[How to synchronize animations from one view to another with matchedGeometryEffect()](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-synchronize-animations-from-one-view-to-another-with-matchedgeometryeffect)" from [Paul Hudson](https://twitter.com/twostraws)) needs to be consistent across both views participating in the animation. It looks like you are using `popRoot.playID`, which should work as long as it is correctly set before the animation starts.

Your `TopVideoView` uses a [`UIHostingController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller) to present the video player, which might complicate the matched geometry effect. SwiftUI animations work best within the SwiftUI view hierarchy, so consider integrating the `TopVideo` directly into the SwiftUI view hierarchy instead of adding it over a window.

```swift
class PopToRoot: ObservableObject { // Environment object accessible anywhere
    @Published var player: AVPlayer? = nil
    @Published var playID: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View { // Top of the view hierarchy
    @EnvironmentObject var popRoot: PopToRoot
    @Namespace private var animationNamespace

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SomeView(animation: animationNamespace)
            
            if popRoot.player != nil {
                TopVideo(player: $popRoot.player)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: popRoot.playID, in: animationNamespace)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView: View { // Subview
    let example = "example URL"
    var animation: Namespace.ID

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            BottomVideoView(url: URL(string: example)!, animation: animation)
            // Additional views
        }
    }
}

struct BottomVideoView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var popRoot: PopToRoot
    let url: URL
    var animation: Namespace.ID
    @State var player: AVPlayer? = nil

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if let vid = player {
                VidPlayer(player: vid)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: url.absoluteString, in: animation)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            popRoot.playID = url.absoluteString
                            popRoot.player = player
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            if player == nil {
                player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                self.player?.play()
            }
        }
    }
}

// No changes needed for VidPlayer and TopVideo
```

The `animationNamespace` is declared in `ContentView` and passed to `SomeView` and `BottomVideoView`. That makes sure the matched geometry effect operates within the same namespace across these views. The `TopVideo` view is directly integrated into the SwiftUI view hierarchy, which should help with the animation.
Make sure the environment object (`PopToRoot`) is correctly passed down to all views that require access to it.

---

> I think the issue is adding the view to the window. I need this functionality though to present the video player about everything including sheets and fullscreencovers.

Matched geometry effect animations are designed to work within the SwiftUI view hierarchy, and using a [`UIHostingController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller) to present a view on top of everything else complicates this.

Since the matched geometry effect relies on both views being in the same view hierarchy and this requirement conflicts with your need to present the view above everything, you might consider implementing a custom animation. You can animate the frame of the `UIHostingController`'s view manually to mimic the matched geometry effect. That involves calculating the starting and ending frames and using UIView animations to transition between them.

For views within the SwiftUI hierarchy, you can use [`.zIndex()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/zindex(_:)) to manage which views are presented on top of others. While this will not help with presenting over fullscreen covers or sheets directly, it is useful for in-hierarchy presentation order management.

Instead of adding the `UIHostingController`'s view to the window directly, consider creating a new `UIWindow` that is presented on top of your current window. That overlay window can be used exclusively for presenting the video player. That approach makes it easier to manage the video player independently of the rest of your UI and can simplify animations since you are moving a window instead of a view within a window.

To integrate this approach with SwiftUI and still trigger animations from SwiftUI views, you can use [`onTapGesture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ontapgesture(count:perform:)) or similar triggers to initiate the presentation and dismissal of the overlay window. You would still use environment objects or shared state management to coordinate the data between your SwiftUI views and the video player being presented in the overlay window.

Assuming you have a method to calculate the starting and ending frames based on your UI layout, your method would be:

```swift
func presentVideoPlayerOverlay(player: AVPlayer, fromStartFrame startFrame: CGRect, toEndFrame endFrame: CGRect) {
    let swiftUIView = TopVideo(player: .constant(player))
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
    hostingController.view.frame = startFrame // Initial frame, possibly matching a SwiftUI view's frame
    
    let overlayWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    overlayWindow.rootViewController = hostingController
    overlayWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        hostingController.view.frame = endFrame // Final frame, e.g., fullscreen
    }) { _ in
        // Animation completion actions if needed
    }
}

// You would call `presentVideoPlayerOverlay` with the appropriate player and frame parameters when you want to present the video player.
```

Comment: I think the issue is adding the view to the window. I need this functionality though to present the video player about everything including sheets and fullscreencovers.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower I have edited the answer to address your comment: not a complete solution, but worth investigating.