# Swift Device Orientation updating incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to detect device orientation in swift so that I can apply the correct orientation to a video. The code I have for updating device orientation works correctly but is extremely sensitive to tiny movements. Holding the device upward and barely tilting it causes the device orientation to update to a landscape orientation even though the phone is basically still portrait. Is there a way to lower the sensitivity for device orientation so that tiny movements dont cause an unwanted update?

Additionally my app does not support landscape in the apps build file. So maybe tracking the apps orientation would not work. I want this specific view to detect orientation so I can adjust a video player to be oriented right.

```
struct TopVideo: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
   if let vid = player {
                let portrait = (orien == .portrait || orien == .unknown || orien == .portraitUpsideDown)
                let width = widthOrHeight(width: true)
                let height = widthOrHeight(width: false)
                
                let vid_width = portrait ? width : (height * CGFloat(aspect.width / aspect.height))
                let vid_height = !portrait ? width : (height * CGFloat(aspect.height / aspect.width))
                
                VidPlayer(player: vid)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees((orien == .portrait || orien == .unknown)  ? 0.0 : orien == .portraitUpsideDown ? 180.0 : orien == .landscapeLeft ? 90 : -90 ))
                    .frame(width: vid_width, height: vid_height)
            }
        }
        .onRotate { newOrientation in
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)){
                orien = newOrientation
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DeviceRotationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let action: (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear()
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                action(UIDevice.current.orientation)
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func onRotate(perform action: @escaping (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(DeviceRotationViewModifier(action: action))
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of watching the device orientation, why not watch the _app_ orientation?

Comment: @matt how do I do that?

Comment: Why are you tracking the orientation? ViewThatFits and SwiftUI.Layout are usually better approaches.

Comment: @loremipsum this view contains a video player. I need to know the orientation to orient my video correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78094943/swift-device-orientation-updating-incorrectly?noredirect=1#comment137677408_78094943) to watch the app orientation instead of the device orientation, you can modify your approach to observe changes in the interface orientation.
That would focus on the orientation of the app's user interface, which might change less frequently than the device's physical orientation, thus providing a less sensitive detection mechanism.

Modify your `DeviceRotationViewModifier` to observe changes in the [`statusBarOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623026-statusbarorientation) of the app's window scene. That requires access to the current [`UIWindowScene`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/) to observe its [`interfaceOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3198088-interfaceorientation).

Make sure your `onRotate` modifier now triggers actions based on the app's interface orientation.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct TopVideo: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Your ZStack content
        }
        .onRotate { newOrientation in
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                // Update your UI based on the newOrientation
                // orien = newOrientation
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AppOrientationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let action: (UIInterfaceOrientation) -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear()
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification)) { _ in
                if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene {
                    action(windowScene.interfaceOrientation)
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func onRotate(perform action: @escaping (UIInterfaceOrientation) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(AppOrientationViewModifier(action: action))
    }
}
```

The `AppOrientationViewModifier` now listens for the `UIApplication.didChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` notification. When the orientation changes, it retrieves the current `UIInterfaceOrientation` from the `UIWindowScene` and triggers the provided action.
The extension method `onRotate` is adapted to accept a closure with a `UIInterfaceOrientation` parameter, reflecting the change to app interface orientation detection.

Again, this assumes your app uses `UIWindowScene` (which is standard for apps targeting iOS 13 and later). If you are supporting older versions of iOS, you might need to adjust the implementation to make sure compatibility.

---

As noted by [lorem ipsum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12738750/lorem-ipsum) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78094943/swift-device-orientation-updating-incorrectly?noredirect=1#comment137679978_78094943), you could also use:

- [`ViewThatFits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewthatfits), which automatically chooses between multiple views based on which one fits the available space best. This is particularly useful in situations where the layout needs to adapt significantly between portrait and landscape orientations without explicitly tracking the orientation state.

  ```swift
  struct AdaptiveVideoLayout: View {
      var body: some View {
          ViewThatFits {
              PortraitVideoPlayer() // A custom view optimized for portrait orientation
              LandscapeVideoPlayer() // A custom view optimized for landscape orientation
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- [`SwiftUI.Layout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layout), introduced in iOS 16, where you can define more complex custom layouts that adapt to the container's size. It offers a more powerful and flexible way to create adaptive UIs that can respond to changes in orientation, screen size, and other factors.

  ```swift
  struct CustomVideoLayout: View {
      var body: some View {
          Layout {
              // Define custom layout logic that adapts to the container size
          }
      }
  }
  ```

---

> I don't want to use a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

True, [`UIApplication.shared.windows`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623104-windows) and [`UIApplication.didChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622991-didchangestatusbarorientationnot) are deprecated.

An alternative approach (besides [`UIViewControllerRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable)) should stay within the SwiftUI framework without reverting to UIKit mechanisms that are either deprecated or considered less idiomatic in pure SwiftUI applications.

You might consider creating a custom [`EnvironmentKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentkey) to propagate orientation changes through the SwiftUI view hierarchy. That would involve using a combination of SwiftUI and UIKit under the hood, but expose the functionality in a way that is idiomatic to SwiftUI.
This is inspired from "[Exploring SwiftUI: Orientation Property Wrapper](https://rryam.com/swiftui-orientation-property-wrapper)" by [Rudrank Riyam](https://rryam.com/rudrank).

```swift
import SwiftUI

// Define an EnvironmentKey for orientation
struct OrientationKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: UIDeviceOrientation = .unknown
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var orientation: UIDeviceOrientation {
        get { self[OrientationKey.self] }
        set { self[OrientationKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

// A ViewModifier that updates the orientation environment value
struct OrientationModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.orientation) var orientation
    let action: (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear()
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                let newOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
                action(newOrientation)
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func onOrientationChange(action: @escaping (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(OrientationModifier(action: action))
    }
}
```

You can use this modifier in your views to get notified of orientation changes without directly interacting with `UIViewControllerRepresentable` or dealing with deprecated APIs:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.orientation) var orientation
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Current orientation: \(orientation.isLandscape ? "Landscape" : "Portrait")")
            .onOrientationChange { newOrientation in
                // Handle orientation change
                print("Orientation changed to: \(newOrientation)")
            }
    }
}
```

By abstracting away the UIKit interaction to a reusable `ViewModifier`, you can avoid the direct use of `UIViewControllerRepresentable` while still achieving what you want.

---

The OP proposes:

> Detecting the device orientation using the default Notification Center updates is not accurate.
>
> Using a custom orientation detector is more customizable. This works with SwiftUI too, just declare a `StateObject` for the following detector.
> Then, in the `onAppear` call the start tracking function and in the `onDisappear` call the stop tracking function.
>
> To get the orientation, use an `onChange` method to listen to changes in **`currentOrientation`**.
> You can adjust the threshold to make this detector more or less sensitive to device movements.

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

public class OrientationTracker: ObservableObject {
    public static let shared = OrientationTracker()
    public static let deviceOrientationChangedNotification = NSNotification.Name("DeviceOrientationChangedNotification")
    public var currentDeviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation = .portrait
    @Published var currentOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation = .portrait
    
    public var affineTransform: CGAffineTransform {
        var angleRadians: CGFloat
        switch currentDeviceOrientation {
        case .portrait:
            angleRadians = 0
        case .landscapeLeft:
            angleRadians = -0.5 * .pi
        case .landscapeRight:
            angleRadians = 0.5 * .pi
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            angleRadians = .pi
        default:
            return .identity
        }
        return CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angleRadians)
    }
    
    let motionManager: CMMotionManager
    let queue: OperationQueue
    
    init() {
        self.motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
        self.queue = OperationQueue()
    }
    
    public func startDeviceOrientationTracking() {
        
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: queue) { accelerometerData, error in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let accelerometerData = accelerometerData else { return }
            
            let newDeviceOrientation = self.deviceOrientation(forAccelerometerData: accelerometerData)
            guard newDeviceOrientation != self.currentDeviceOrientation else { return }
            self.currentDeviceOrientation = newDeviceOrientation
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.currentOrientation = newDeviceOrientation
            }
        
            let name = OrientationTracker.deviceOrientationChangedNotification
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name,
                                            object: nil,
                                            userInfo: nil)
            
        }
    }
    
    public func stopDeviceOrientationTracking() {
        motionManager.stopAccelerometerUpdates()
    }
    
    func deviceOrientation(forAccelerometerData accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData) -> UIDeviceOrientation {
        let treshold = 0.55
        if accelerometerData.acceleration.x >= treshold {
            return .landscapeRight
        } else if accelerometerData.acceleration.x <= -treshold {
            return .landscapeLeft
        } else if accelerometerData.acceleration.y <= -treshold {
            return .portrait
        } else if accelerometerData.acceleration.y >= treshold {
            return .portraitUpsideDown
        } else {
            return currentDeviceOrientation
        }
    }
}
```

That uses a custom `OrientationTracker` class utilizing the [Core Motion framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion) for detecting device orientation changes. It directly addresses the issue of sensitivity to minor movements that the default `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` might have, by allowing for a customizable threshold for detecting orientation changes.
It utilizes the accelerometer data from the device to determine its orientation (a more direct method of detecting physical orientation changes compared to relying on system notifications which might be delayed or filtered).

By adjusting the threshold value in the `deviceOrientation(forAccelerometerData:)` method, you can control how sensitive the orientation tracker is to changes. That means you can make the detection less prone to switching orientations due to minor tilts or movements.
By making the `OrientationTracker` an `ObservableObject` and using `@Published` for the `currentOrientation` property, it seamlessly integrates with SwiftUI's data flow. That allows for reactive UI updates in response to orientation changes.

The `startDeviceOrientationTracking` and `stopDeviceOrientationTracking` methods provide explicit control over when the app is actively tracking orientation changes. It conserves resources when orientation tracking is not needed and for avoiding unnecessary updates.

To integrate this `OrientationTracker` into a SwiftUI view, you would typically do the following:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var orientationTracker = OrientationTracker.shared

    var body: some View {
        Text("Current orientation: \(orientationTracker.currentOrientation.rawValue)")
            .onChange(of: orientationTracker.currentOrientation) { newOrientation in
                // Handle orientation change
                print("Orientation changed to: \(newOrientation)")
            }
            .onAppear {
                orientationTracker.startDeviceOrientationTracking()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                orientationTracker.stopDeviceOrientationTracking()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like a good idea, but you have two warnings.  So wouldn't it be better if you just get notified for `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification`?

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower As one of the warnings suggests, it seems that you can use `viewWillTransition(to:with:)`, which requires that you use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower OK. I have edited the answer to include an alternative approach.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Thank you for the feedback. I have included your solution in the answer, with some comments. Let me know if I misinterpreted anything.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put a `GeometryReader` around your content, to measure the size of the view. This approach works with iPad split screen too.

At the simplest level, you could pass a flag like `isLandscape` to your top-level view. The view can then base its layout on this flag. If you really need to perform some kind of action when the orientation changes, an `.onChange` callback can be used:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    private func mainContent(isLandscape: Bool) -> some View {
        Text("\(isLandscape ? "Landscape" : "Portrait") orientation")
            .frame(width: isLandscape ? 300 : 200, height: isLandscape ? 200 : 300)
            .background(.yellow)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

            // pre iOS 17: .onChange(of: isLandscape) { newVal in
            .onChange(of: isLandscape) { oldVal, newVal in
                print("orientation changed to \(newVal ? "landscape" : "portrait")")
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            mainContent(isLandscape: proxy.size.height < proxy.size.width)
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware the two-thirds split-screen on iPad is pretty close to square on some devices. So instead of passing a boolean flag, it might be more useful to pass the actual view size and maybe the safe area insets too. You might like to use a struct to encapsulate this information. This struct could then provide some read-only computed properties:

```swift
struct ViewSize {

    let size: CGSize
    let safeAreaInsets: EdgeInsets

    var width: CGFloat {
        size.width
    }

    var height: CGFloat {
        size.height
    }

    var fullWidth: CGFloat {
        size.width + safeAreaInsets.leading + safeAreaInsets.trailing
    }

    var fullHeight: CGFloat {
        size.height + safeAreaInsets.top + safeAreaInsets.bottom
    }

    var minDimension: CGFloat {
        min(size.width, size.height)
    }

    var maxDimension: CGFloat {
        max(size.width, size.height)
    }

    var isLandscape: Bool {
        size.height < size.width
    }

    // etc.

}
```

Comment: If the primary need is to adjust the layout of the UI based on the current size of the view, especially to support dynamic environments like split-screen multitasking, that seems more straightforward and effective than my answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks this doesn't work for me though.

Comment: Thanks this doesn't work for me though I tried using your exact code and isLandScape is always false even on a real device. I think its because my app doesn't support landscape mode in the build file but I want this specific view to detect the orientation so I can orient+resize the video player.