Text markdown makes UI slow/framy
I have a basic scroll view with content, and the content is all inside a LazyVStack. When I have many subviews with my custom text markdown view then the scroll view becomes very slow and framy/glitchy. I'm assuming this is because my custom view has a lot of overhead to separate each piece of the text and display it. Given a string in swift ui, I simply want to style each component (hashtag, @ tag, web-link) in a different way and handle clicks on each of these components differently. How can I improve my approach so that it has no negative effects on the scroll view. If there is a better way to approach this I'd appreciate the help.
How it works:
I separate each string into an array of components inside the init. Then each component is laid out inside CustomLayout, which is a custom layout guide that positions subviews continuously left to right, top to bottom, to replicate a continuous string.
copy pastable code
import SwiftUI

private let linkDetector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)

struct MarkDownText: View {
    let text: String
    let links: [NSTextCheckingResult]
    
    init (_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
        let nsText = text as NSString
        let wholeString = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsText.length)
        links = linkDetector.matches(in: text, options: [], range: wholeString)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        MarkDownTextView(text: text, links: links)
    }
}

struct MarkDownTextView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    enum Component {
        case text(String)
        case link(String, URL)
        case username(String)
        case hashtag(String)
    }

    let text: String
    @State var components: [Component]

    init(text: String, links: [NSTextCheckingResult]) {
        self.text = text
        let nsText = text as NSString
        
        var components: [Component] = []
        var index = 0
        for result in links {
            if result.range.location > index {
                let sub_str = nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index, length: result.range.location - index))
                let ats = separateTextAndTags(input: sub_str)
                
                ats.forEach { element in
                    if element.hasPrefix("@") && element.count < 13 {
                        components.append(.username(element))
                    } else if element.hasPrefix("#") && element.count < 40 {
                        components.append(.hashtag(element))
                    } else {
                        components.append(.text(element))
                    }
                }
            }
            components.append(.link(nsText.substring(with: result.range), result.url!))
            index = result.range.location + result.range.length
        }
        if index < nsText.length {
            let sub_str = nsText.substring(from: index)
            let ats = separateTextAndTags(input: sub_str)
            
            ats.forEach { element in
                if element.hasPrefix("@") && element.count < 13 {
                    components.append(.username(element))
                } else if element.hasPrefix("#") && element.count < 40 {
                    components.append(.hashtag(element))
                } else {
                    components.append(.text(element))
                }
            }
        }
        _components = State(initialValue: components)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomLayout(spacing: 0){
            ForEach(Array(components.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { _, component in
                switch component {
                case .text(let text):
                    Text(verbatim: text).font(.subheadline).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                case .link(let text, _):
                    Button {
                        if let url = URL(string: text) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text(verbatim: text).foregroundColor(.blue).font(.subheadline)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    }
                case .username(let text):
                    Button(action: {
                        Text(text)
                            .font(.subheadline).bold()
                            .foregroundStyle(.red)
                    }, label: {
                        Text(text)
                            .font(.subheadline).bold()
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                    })
                case .hashtag(let hash):
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("\(hash) view")
                    } label: {
                        Text(hash)
                            .italic()
                            .font(.subheadline).bold()
                            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func separateTextAndTags(input: String) -> [String] {
    var resultArray: [String] = []
    var currentToken = ""

    for character in input {
        if character == "@" || character == "#" {
            if !currentToken.isEmpty {
                resultArray.append(currentToken)
                currentToken = ""
            }
            currentToken += String(character)
        } else if character.isWhitespace {
            if currentToken.count > 1 && (currentToken.hasPrefix("@") || currentToken.hasPrefix("#")) {
                resultArray.append(currentToken)
                currentToken = ""
            }
            currentToken += String(character)
        } else {
            currentToken += String(character)
        }
    }

    if !currentToken.isEmpty {
        resultArray.append(currentToken)
    }

    return resultArray
}

struct CustomLayout: Layout {
    var alignment: Alignment = .leading
    var spacing: CGFloat = 0
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let maxWidth = proposal.width ?? 0
        var height: CGFloat = 0
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)
        
        for (index, row) in rows.enumerated() {
            if index == (rows.count - 1) {
                height += row.maxHeight(proposal)
            } else {
                height += row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing
            }
        }
        
        return .init(width: maxWidth, height: height)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        var origin = bounds.origin
        let maxWidth = bounds.width
        
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)
        
        for row in rows {
            let leading: CGFloat = bounds.maxX - maxWidth
            let trailing = bounds.maxX - (row.reduce(CGFloat.zero) { partialResult, view in
                let width = view.sizeThatFits(proposal).width
                
                if view == row.last {
                    return partialResult + width
                }
                return partialResult + width + spacing
            })
            let center = (trailing + leading) / 2
            
            origin.x = (alignment == .leading ? leading : alignment == .trailing ? trailing : center)
            
            for view in row {
                let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
                view.place(at: origin, proposal: proposal)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            }
        
            origin.y += (row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing)
        }
    }
    
    func generateRows(_ maxWidth: CGFloat, _ proposal: ProposedViewSize, _ subviews: Subviews) -> [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] {
        var row: [LayoutSubviews.Element] = []
        var rows: [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] = []
        
        var origin = CGRect.zero.origin
        
        for view in subviews {
            let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
            
            if (origin.x + viewSize.width + spacing) > maxWidth {
                rows.append(row)
                row.removeAll()
                origin.x = 0
                row.append(view)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            } else {
                row.append(view)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            }
        }

        if !row.isEmpty {
            rows.append(row)
            row.removeAll()
        }
        
        return rows
    }
}


It might help if your custom layout performed some caching. The documentation page Composing custom layouts with SwiftUI shows how.

Why not use actual markdown instead of a complex layout

@loremipsum how do I do that? I thought markdown only lets me style the string in a custom way, not detect clicks to each component.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192976/listen-to-link-click-in-swiftui-textview/75201168#75201168

You can use regex to make the replacements to link

@loremipsum thanks, I am trying to implement this but I see no way to customize the style for different components such as tags, hashtags, or phone numbers. For example how do I make hashtags orange with this method?

That would require AttributedString, it is a bit more involved

@loremipsum I found this example on attributed strings, but it seems the same as what Im doing right now, splitting the components in different pieces to specific styling. Any tips on how to use your first suggestion LocalizedStringKey with AttributedStrings?

I have never combined them. Examine what the encoded/decoded AttributedString looks like see if you can adjust the regex replacement to enclose whatever AttributedString looks like. There might be a way AttributedString can read HTML so there has to be a pattern.
