# in swiftUI ForEach loop displays words separated in different lines and not keeping words in original text form

Tags: swiftui

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKWKU.png)ForEach loop displays words separated in different lines and not keeping words in original text form. whether in  HStack or VStack still there is same issue.

[HStack words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtuU6.png)
[VStack words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFr2p.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let mainText = "In the midst of a wartime evacuation, a British aeroplane crashes on or near an isolated island in a remote region of the Pacific Ocean."
    
    let wordsToMakeTapable = ["evacuation,", "crashes", "isolated"]
    let definitions = ["evacuation,": "make empty", "crashes": "hit", "isolated": "far away"]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let words = mainText.components(separatedBy: " ")
        
        HStack {
            ForEach(words, id: \.self) { word in
                if wordsToMakeTapable.contains(word) {
                    Text(word)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .bold()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            switch word {
                            case "evacuation":
                                print(definitions["evacuation"]!)
                            case "crashes":
                                print(definitions["crashes"]!)
                            case "isolated":
                                print(definitions["isolated"]!)
                            default:
                                break
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    Text(word)
                }
                Spacer()
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: The words are in an `HStack`. Put them in a `VStack`. They can't behave the same...

Comment: thank you for your reply. i upload a photo. still the words will be displayed vertically

Comment: Neither `HStack` or `VStack` will do what you want in this case. Maybe look at using an attributed string? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624838/swiftui-tappable-subtext

Comment: You should look into `AttributedString`

Comment: thank you for your help. attributedString solved the issue