# How to add onTapGesture AND underline to specific word in a SwiftUI Text view?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I need to make a specific *underlined* word be tappable within a paragraph of text for a SwiftUI view.

Currently my onTapGesture applies to the whole paragraph but I need it only on **Text(labelOne)** (AKA Action).

I cannot use onTapGesture AND .underline on Text(labelOne) because I get the error *"Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'Text'"* if underline() is placed under onTapGesture {}  OR *"Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'Text'"* if I put onTapGesture{} under .underline().

In this case I am combining Text views, **Text("Action") + Text("end of first sentence.") + Text("Body Text")** so this is what prevents me from combining .onTapGesture with .underline()

It would be preferable to use a Button inside the paragraph so the user gets visual feedback that Action was pressed but not sure if that is possible without it being separate from the text?

[image]

**If put Text in an HStack (which would allow me to add .underline() & .onTapGesture{} to a specific view) it looks bad if the sentence grows for Text(labelTwo), see below**

[image]

```
struct TextView: View {
    let labelOne: String = "Action"
    let labelTwo: String = "end of first sentence."
    let text: String = "Begining of second sentence lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(labelOne) // <- Needs to be tappable, solely.
                .underline()
            + Text(" \(labelTwo) ")
            + Text(text)
        }
        .onTapGesture { // <- Applies to whole paragraph (BAD)
            print("Action pressed")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624838/swiftui-tappable-subtext ? Add `.onTapGesture{}` only to the first `Text()`?

Comment: In this case I am combining Text views, Text("Action") + Text("end of first sentence.") + Text("Body Text") so this is what prevents combining .onTapGesture with .underline()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this in three steps:

First, define a custom URL scheme for your app, e.g.

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.example.myapp</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myappurl</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

This can be done in your target's Info tab:
[image]

Secondly, change your first text to use Markdown, using `Action` as the link text and a url that uses your newly defined URL scheme, e.g.

```
Text("[\(labelOne)](myappurl://action)").underline()
```

Finally, add the `.onOpenURL` modifier. When you tap the link the app will try to open itself, and it can be handled by this modifier.

```
HStack {
    Text("[\(labelOne)](myappurl://action)").underline() +
    Text(" \(labelTwo) ") +
    Text(text)
}.onOpenURL { link in

    // do whatever action you want on tapping the link


}
```

Comment: I am not trying to open an external link in my case but call a function, would this still work in my case? Thank you

Comment: Absolutely - the url is a custom one that will only "open" in your app, so tapping the link will cause the `.onOpenURL` function to be fired, where you can do whatever you want. Look at the code, you'll see the url is `myappurl://action`. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar problem, essentially trying to embed Button views (with string labels) into a sentence (or paragraph). [Ashley's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123632/ashley-mills) answer helped me figure out a solution that'll take an array of elements and produce a single Text view with embedded text "buttons". Here's the code.

```
extension Array where Element == InlineButtonElement {
@ViewBuilder func makeButtons (prepend: String, append: String) -> some View {
        Group {
            self.enumerated().reduce(Text("\(prepend) "), { last, next in
                let (idx, spec) = next
                var elementPrepend: String
                if idx == self.indices.lowerBound {
                    elementPrepend = ""
                } else if idx == self.indices.upperBound - 1 {
                    elementPrepend = " and "
                } else {
                    elementPrepend = ", "
                }
                var label = spec.label
                label.link = URL(string: "url://resource/\(idx)")!
                return last + Text(elementPrepend) + Text(label)
            }) + Text(" \(append)")
        }
        .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction(handler: { url in
            if let idx = Int(url.lastPathComponent) {
                self[idx].action()
            }
            return .handled
        }))
    }
}
struct InlineButtonElement {
    var label: AttributedString
    var action: (() -> Void)
    init (label: String, attributes: AttributeContainer = AttributeContainer(), _ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
        var attrLabel = AttributedString(stringLiteral: label)
        self.label = attrLabel.settingAttributes(attributes)
    }
}
```

At the call site:

```
 struct Content: View {
    @State var path: NavigationPath = .init()
    @State var intElements = [1,2,3,4,5]
    @State var strElements = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                intElements
                    .map { element in
                        var attr = AttributeContainer()
                        attr.foregroundColor = .blue
                        return InlineButtonElement(label: "Label \(element)", attributes: attr) {
                            path.append(element)
                        }
                    }
                    .makeButtons(prepend: "Inline buttons ", append: " built in SwiftUI")
                strElements
                    .map { element in
                        var attr = AttributeContainer()
                        attr.foregroundColor = .blue
                        return InlineButtonElement(label: "Label \(element)", attributes: attr) {
                            path.append(element)
                        }
                    }
                    .makeButtons(prepend: "Inline buttons ", append: " built in SwiftUI")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { newInt in
                IntView_destination(newInt)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { newStr in
                StrView_destination(newStr)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct IntView_destination: View {
    @State var int: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("I am an int \(int)")
    }
    init (_ int: Int) {
        _int = State(initialValue: int)
    }
}
struct StrView_destination: View {
    @State var str: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("I am a string \(str)")
    }
    init (_ str: String) {
        _str = State(initialValue: str)
    }
}
```

Produces this:

[image]

The "InlineButtonElement" struct creates a Button-like element that can be styled using AttributedString modifiers created using an AttributedContainer, which'll give you options for styling the link string.

Maybe a little overkill to get the commas and "ands" correct... :)