# Show array of text like paragraph but each text will be tappable in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
@State var content: [SuraReadModeAyath] = []
ForEach(content.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    let sura = content[index]
    let text = isBanglaSelected ? sura.transliterationBn ?? "" : sura.arabicUthmani ?? ""
    Text(text)
        .font(isBanglaSelected ? Font.custom("Inter", size: customFontSize - 10): Font.custom("KFGQPC Uthmanic Script HAFS", size: customFontSize))
        .foregroundStyle(index == suraDetailsVM.serial ? .deenThemeColor: .deenBlack)
        .multilineTextAlignment(isBanglaSelected ? .leading : .trailing)
        .padding(.vertical, 4)
        .id(index)
        .onTapGesture {
            AudioPlayerManager.shared.isAudioClicked = true
            suraDetailsVM.serial = index
            if suraDetailsVM.serial == index {
                suraDetailsVM.isPlayDictionary[suraDetailsVM.serial] = true
                if suraDetailsVM.isPlayDictionary[suraDetailsVM.serial] ?? false {
                    audioControllerVM.suraDetailsAudio(index: suraDetailsVM.serial, suraDetailsVM: suraDetailsVM)
                }
            }
        }

}
```

#content contain suraReadModeVM.ayaths

In above code, I get all text and each of them individually clickable. The problem is I want to show it like a paragraph. functionality will be same as it is. Now each text start with new line.
I am using Xcode 15+, iOS 16.0, SwiftUI

Comment: Please include a [mre]. No one can run the code you've posted.

Comment: Think like I have an array of text with id, I need to perform some action on tap of that text. Here I used foreach loop. Everything is right, the problem is it shows each text with new line. I need it like a paragraph

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77127208/5133585) in the duplicate target is how I recommend to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in  making  it inside a **forEach** , you need to combine the whole text inside one String/AttributedString , then assign it to one **Text**

**Edit:** This is a full example of what you can do to combine them and also be able to identify each clicked item , Btw combining is optional you can use `generateContent` method directly.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ItemsView(tags: Array(1...100).map {  "\($0)" })
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


struct ItemsView: View {
    var tags: [String]
    @State private var totalHeight = CGFloat.zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                self.generateContent(in: geometry)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: totalHeight)
    }
    private func generateContent(in g: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        var width = CGFloat.zero
        var height = CGFloat.zero
        let lastTitle = tags.last!
        return ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { item in
                self.item(for: item)
                    .padding([.horizontal, .vertical], 4)
                    .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { d in
                        if (abs(width - d.width) > g.size.width)  {
                            width = 0
                            height -= d.height
                        }
                        let result = width
                        if item == lastTitle {
                            width = 0 //last item
                        } else {
                            width -= d.width
                        }
                        return result
                    })
                    .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: { d in
                        let result = height
                        if item == lastTitle {
                            height = 0 // last item
                        }
                        return result
                    })
            }
        }.background(viewHeightReader($totalHeight))
    }
    private func item(for item: String) -> some View {
        Text(item)
            .padding(.horizontal,5)
            .padding(.vertical,5)
            .onTapGesture {
               print(item)
            }
    }
    private func viewHeightReader(_ binding: Binding<CGFloat>) -> some View {
        return GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
            let rect = geometry.frame(in: .local)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                binding.wrappedValue = rect.size.height
            }
            return .clear
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Then how I will access each text individually? I need to click each text

Comment: It's working but  partially, next text will start immediate of previous text if there has any space. Now it start immediate of next text if only it fits to the rest of screen. Otherwise start with new line. Thanks for your help