# How to give an outline color to text?

Tags: swift, swiftui, text

I want to have an outline color for my text in SwiftUI. This is the code and I do not find any modifier for this goal:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Outline")
    }
}
```

The goal I want is like this:

[image]

Comment: most of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334125/how-to-make-text-stroke-in-swiftui) should help

Comment: But those answers does not seem attacking the issue in right way, I mean we need a path or something like that for out line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make text stroke in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334125/how-to-make-text-stroke-in-swiftui). Specifically the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623596/20287183) works quite easily.

Comment: Also, once Apple adds proper support for `AttributedString` and `strokeColor`/`strokeWidth`, the more flexible solution will be [How do you stroke text using AttributedString in iOS 15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70746438/how-do-you-stroke-text-using-attributedstring-in-ios-15).